# How to define maxlength of @Html.DisplayFor in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm new in MVC
I have `textarea` in create view whice take max of nvarchar but in display mode (Index page) all of this character display to me so I want to define the count of character whice display in my index page in Model

```
public string Description { get; set; }
```

In `Create` controller

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In `Index` controller

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].Description)
```

and my problem is in this image:
[image]

Comment: You cannot, But you could ese a view model with a property for `Description` and map the data model property to it using `String.Substring()` or use css to style it (e.g. width and display ellipses)

Comment: Which of the 2 options I mentioned?

Comment: the one (String.Substring())

Comment: In addition to the answers, refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25o3zdhq/1/) for an example of using css

Comment: @Stephen, Issue with using a CSS solution, such as the one you've provided, is it cannot specify an exact length to cut-off the text, which is what the OP is requesting. Otherwise, it's a great alternative.

Comment: @Chase, But why would OP want an exact length - it would then mean making the table column a certain width to accommodate it which would vary slightly across browsers and depend on other factors such as font style, size etc. - the css solution means it will fill up all available space irrespective of any other style issues.

Comment: @Stephen I completely agree, but the OP has asked specifically for a solution that allows him to define the cutoff length. Within those constraints, your CSS solution does not meet the criteria. Your comments, however, will hopefully prompt him to reconsider his ultimate solution to take the better approach you've suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You need to basically do a substring on your property of string type and specify how many characters you want. You might consider creating an extension method to do that.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToSafeSubString(this string value, int count)
    {
         return value != null && value.Length > count ?
                                                   value.Substring(0, count) : value;
    }
}
```

And in your razor view you can call it like

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{      
    var descTrimmed= Model[i].Description.ToSafeSubString(10);

    @Html.DisplayFor(f => descTrimmed)

}
```

Or if you have a view model for your index page, when you map your domain entities to your view model list, you can call the extension method on the string property.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var userList= db.Users.Select(s=> new UserViewModel {
                                  UserName =s.UserName,
                                  Description=s.Description.ToSafeSubString(10) })
                              .ToList();
   return View(userList);
}
```

Comment: I do what you do exactly but the problem still be with me and I cant understand your answer

Comment: what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

When editing, you can limit the text using `maxlength` attribute:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "20" })
```

When displaying, you can limit the text using the `Substring()` method, but must use a variable to store the result since `DisplayFor` cannot operate on a method result:

```
string desc = Model[i].Description.Substring(0, 20);
@Html.DisplayFor(x => desc)
```

Comment: It give me this error
"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: You have to use `Display` and not `DisplayFor`. That was fixed in an edit; refresh to update.

Comment: I do that then it give me another error
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Is your model a collection? If not, the `[i]` shouldn't be there for the display. Updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: Or if `Description` is null, then you need to check for that as well.

Comment: My model must be collection and I checked for null and all isn't null and refresh then run my project but this time there aren't any error but my all fields of description is null in my view page

Comment: Okay, then the `[i]` is required. If you're getting the above-mentioned error, it means that you have a null value somewhere. Ensure with the debugger that your model is being created properly and that `Description` for each item in the collection is non-null. You may need to perform some additional steps in your controller to achieve this.

Comment: @Chase, `@Html.Display()` refers to a property of the model and `Model[i].Description.Substring(0, 20)` is not a property of the model

Comment: @Stephen, you are correct! Thanks for pointing that out. In that regard, Shyju's answer is the best.

Comment: Personally I would just use css :)

Comment: @Karim: I've updated my answer with a solution, which is a simplified version of Shyju's -- no additional extension method required. However, for the record, I think Shyju's answer is superior and should be implemented if you can understand it.